# How do I get changes from GitHUB to my local machine?

Tags: git, github, pull

I accepted a pull request from my developer and merged his changes into my repo on GitHUB.

I tried to do a pull from GitHUB to my local machine using:

```
git pull https://github.com:username/RepoName.git
```

AND

```
git pull origin master
```

But I get this error:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I am still quite new to Git, so I'm not sure exactly what to do here.

If it helps, my local dev environment is using MAMP PRO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably wrong permissions set on your `.git` folder. Try:

```
sudo chown -R <your_user> .git
```

And if that doesn't fix it, try:

```
sudo chown -R <your_user> .
```

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to initiate the pull. But I generated two more errors with specific files


    error: unable to unlink old 'path-to-file' (Permission denied)
    error: unable to unlink old 'path-to-file2' (Permission denied)

Ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R <your_user> .`

Comment: Since your comment seems to have enabled the OP to fix the problem, I've merged it into the answer.